# Using ng serve --host x.x.x.x doesn't work

Tags: angular-cli, host

Angular CLI running the command `ng serve -host 192.168.x.x` (replacing x with the correct values for my machine's IP address on the local network) does not allow access from other devices on my network.

Angular CLI: 8.0.6
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.3

I have attempted creating firewall rules, disabling firewall altogether, disabling virus protection, and also using the `--disable-host-check` flag. Also tried using the 0.0.0.0 value for IP instead of actual IP. None of this works. I **am** able to access the app from the local machine it's running on using the IP address and port.

I imagine this is some network or router issue but I haven't found any solutions on any other Stack Overflow (nor any other internet search results) for this issue. All solutions provided in those searches & answers have not worked. Is there something on the other machines or phones I have to setup to have this work?

Answer (score 1):

`ng serve --host 192.168.x.x`

You should add two `-` (dash symbol) before the `host` to make this work.